# Prevent batch file in CMD from closing without using Pause

Tags: batch-file

Currently I want to run a batch file that fires the command `git log` and show me that log. 
After that I need to be able to commit and view the status so this prompt may not disappear after a key press.

I've searched the net and the only answer people have is `pause` which close the prompt after a keypress.

Does anyone have the solution for me? Currently I made a shortcut to `cmd.exe` and made the target my folder, but I want to execute some commands also.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This (below) tested OK in Windows 7.  To exit the window it creates, type "exit" when done.

> **start cmd /K "cd \[the-target-folder] && git log"**

Where:
  [the-target-folder] you replace with your target folder

Note:
  && lets you run two commands on one line
  /K is a parameter to the cmd shell program which which carries out the command specified by string and remains.

Comment: Thanks, I have another solution, add in the properties target the command. Start in the target folder. Your solution is working also. Thanks again.